# Are there plastics harder than heat-treated steel?

Tags: materials, plastic

I've been reading that plastics harder than steel have been developed.

The drill guide in the photo is made of heat-treated steel. Is there a plastic hard enough to substitute for heat-treated steel, hard enough not to be abraded by the spinning drill bits, which  would also be not more expensive than steel, or less expensive?

[image: hardened-steel drill guide]

Comment: Nope. There's heat treated steel and then there's heat treated steel. I am even surprised and skeptical  there are plastics supposedly harder than barely heat treated steel. The steel in your drill is seriously heat treated steel. Also, you realize drills only cut on the tip right? Not the flutes? They are drills, not endmills.

Comment: What does your reading tell you? Not sure we have read what you have as you don’t quote it, or provide a link.

Comment: !@DKNguyen With the application I have in mind (drilling wood) you raise and lower the drill bit to expel the cuttings as you drill deeper, and if it's not an absolutely perfect mating between bit and guide there's slight kilter to the bit, it's a tad off-axis, which could start scraping up the inside of the guide hole.

Comment: @SolarMike: Obviously, what I've been reading didn't distinguish between "steel" and "heat-treated steel", and that's why I'm asking here.  You don't need to know what I've been reading to be able to answer the question; all you need is knowledge of the subject, and if you don't have that knowledge, why not treat the question as one where you have nothing factual to contribute?

Comment: @tim "I've been reading" might mean reading randos on the internet

Comment: @TigerGuy : You know, I could have eliminated that clause from the question. It has little bearing other than to indicate that I've done some reading but couldn't find the answer.